# Why is Request.Content.ReadAsAsync case insensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Suppose I have the json payload sent from the client side as following

```
{"Number": 2, "number": 4}
```

Over on the server side, I have this model class.

```
public class Arg
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

The payload is deserialised in my controller like so:

```
Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Arg>();
```

Why is `Arg.Number` == 4? How can I make `ReadAsAsync` case sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

Deserialization done via Json.NET. I am digging into process and end up with next code:

```
public JsonProperty GetClosestMatchProperty(string propertyName)
{
    JsonProperty property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (property == null)
        property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    return property;
}
```

So as you can see, if it fails to get property using `String.Ordinal` comparer, it will try `String.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, and thats why it overrides your value.

For name I see only one solution to add dummy property to catch this value:

```
public class Arg
{
    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("number")]
    public int SmallNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new property in your custom deserializer

```
public class Arg
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

Tested using newtonsoft

Trying to defining your class as wont work

```
public class Arg
{
    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```